# CompileError using Enthought's scipy.weave on MacOSX

Tags: macos, scipy, enthought

I try to use packages that use `scipy.weave` for numeric optimization, and are met with a CompileError from the `scipy.weave.inline` calls.

Some experimentation brings out a minimal failing example:

```
import scipy.weave
scipy.weave.inline('printf("%d\\n",1);')
```

which results in a massive error dump that I for space reason have put on pastebin: http://pastebin.com/0QR4kq2V

The first error in the dump is

```
/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/complex:47:28: error: bits/c++config.h: No such file or directory
```

and the last output is

```
CompileError: error: Command "g++ -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -arch i386 -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk -DNDEBUG -g -O3 -arch i386 -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/weave -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/weave/scxx -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/include/python2.7 -c /Users/mik/.python27_compiled/sc_f6039f30c0a12f4687924b6a12ef83730.cpp -o /var/folders/_z/qd8rt65n1n56_nvv4nyy7xlh0000gn/T/mik/python27_intermediate/compiler_ecdbc4f3f030692747d93319f8d429b2/Users/mik/.python27_compiled/sc_f6039f30c0a12f4687924b6a12ef83730.o" failed with exit status 1
```

I run MacOSX 10.8.4,

```
> g++ --version
i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-g++-4.2 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.11.00)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

and

```
> python --version
Python 2.7.3 -- EPD 7.3-2 (32-bit)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've not used weave at all myself, so I don't know if it has specific SDK requirements, but I suspect that the issue is that you should not be using the 10.5 SDK with the newer Xcode that you appear to be using.  I also have that version and it only has the 10.7 and 10.8 SDKs installed.  Several releases back Xcode stopped using the /Developer folder and it is all installed inside the Xcode application bundle now.  So the first thing I would try would be to move /Developer somewhere out of the way and try building again and see if that takes care of it.  If so then you should be able to remove /Developer entirely.

Comment: Whoa. `sudo mv /Developer /Developer.bak` and all of a sudden it all works. Thank you!!